# check if there is any more node preceding in same section

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below type of XML structure

```
<root>
    <Section>
     <A></A>
     <B></B>
     <A></A>
    </Section>
    <Section>
     <A></A>
     <B></B>
     <A></A>
    </section>
   </root>
```

Here under each section there are 2 tags namely `A` and `B` but also there are 2 `A` nodes,
 Here i want to check with XPATH(XSLT2.0) if there are any preceding `A` under same `Section`, when i used `Preceding::A`, it is selecting everything i.e. it is not checking if it is in the same section or in different, but it is checking if there is a preceding `A`, but i want to check for preceding `A` in same `Section`, please let me know how can i do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply want to check `preceding-sibling::A`.

Comment: doesn't this mean that there should be `A` just before the current `A`, without any other nodes(here `B`) in between?

Comment: No, `preceding-sibling::A` checks whether there is any `A` element on the preceding sibling axis. You might want to try to read an XPath tutorial: http://www.xmlplease.com/axis

Answer (score 0):

If the `A` elements are all siblings then [Martin's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25056579/592139) of `preceding-sibling::A` is the simplest one.  Alternatively you can let the template matcher do the work for you if you define separate templates for the first and subsequent `A` elements

```
<xsl:template match="A[1]">
  <!-- fires for the first A in each section -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="A">
  <!-- fires for A elements other than the first one -->
</xsl:template>
```

If the `A` elements can be at different levels, e.g.

```
<root>
 <Section>
  <A></A>
  <B></B>
  <A></A>
 </Section>
 <Section>
  <A></A>
  <B><A/></B>
  <C><A></A></C>
 </Section>
</root>
```

then you will need to be a bit more creative with the filtering.  In "document order" a child element is considered to be *after* its parent so you could do something like

```
preceding::A[. >> current()/ancestor::Section[1]]
```

(i.e. all the preceding `A` elements that follow the *current node*'s nearest `Section` ancestor in document order).